# Is it possible to only specify one action (get/set) of an Automatic Property and have the other implemented?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm pretty new to C# and have am entirely self-taught with trial and (a lot of) error, so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.

So far, when creating classes, I have pretty much just made every variable public so I can do what I want with them.

After reading a lot about why this is a bad idea (not that I fully understand it), I now tend to write:

```
public string name { get; set; }
```

Instead of what I used previously:

```
public string name;
```

I understand the shorthand when it is this simple (and I can see why it's useful for inserting break points, and using things like: public string name { get; private set; }.

However, what is the shorthand for the following:

```
private double _grip;
public double grip
{
    get
    {
        return _grip;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > 100) { _grip = 100; }
        else if (value < 0) { _grip = 0; }
        else { _grip = value; }
    }
}
```

It seems a bit clumsy to have to declare a private variable every time I want to put conditions on the variable.

What I want to write is something like this:

```
public double grip
{
    get;
    set
    {
        if (value > 100) { grip = 100; }
        else if (value < 0) { grip = 0; }
        else { grip = value; }
    }
}
```

And have it neatly on one line once the get and set are minimised. However that doesn't work (though I did get my first ever stack overflow error, which was fun).

So - is there a short hand for the above? I have tried to search and read a lot of info on `getters` and `setters` and couldn't find something that does this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# property, is it possible to get around defining get without defining set (no backing variable)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829582/c-sharp-property-is-it-possible-to-get-around-defining-get-without-defining-set)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you provide a custom implementation for one of your methods (*getter* or *setter*) your property is no longer an *auto-implemented* property.So you need to keep using this version:

```
private double _grip;
public double grip
{
    get
    {
        return _grip;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > 100) { _grip = 100; }
        else if (value < 0) { _grip = 0; }
        else { _grip = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason this is true is because you don't have access to the compiler-generated private member that underpins the automatic property, so `grip = value` isn't going to work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The reason this is true is because that's what the C# specification says/allows :|

Comment: @user2864740: Actually, the real reason this is true is because **the compiler complies with the C# specification.**  The specification says: *"Because the backing field is inaccessible, it can be read and written only through the [automatic] property accessors, even within the containing type."*